# Date() javascript format for timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s)

Tags: javascript

I want to set `dateTime: 2017-11-29 12:00:00` in javascript

Then I've used function `Date().getTime()` and result it's not what i want.

**Question:** How to convert `new Date()` for result `2017-11-29 12:00:00` ?

Comment: `H:i:s`? what is `i`?

Comment: *How to convert*: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: @Rajesh Ah i mean Hours:Min:Sec I'll update that